# inf and nan values with iterations

Tags: python

There is the code before with the Rs values

```
from numpy import exp as e
Ri = 9
Rr = 19/2
Rs = 10
i = 0
Er = 0
Rra = 0
x = 1

def F(n):
    return 745*(1-e(-x/10))-49*x
```

#Funcion para calcular el error relativo
def error (Rra,Rrn):
Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
return Erel

```
print ('{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format('# iter','Ri','Rs','Rr','F(Ri)','Erel(%)'))
      
while (i < 10):
    Er = error(Rra,Rr)
    Rra = Rr `#Rra sera el Rr anterior para determinar el error relativo`
    if F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es',Rr)

    Rr = (Ri + Rs) / 2
    i = i + 1

    #Condicional para el primer error relativo

    if i == 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr)))
    elif i > 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.10f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr),Er))
```

I am developing an exercise in which I must use the Regula Falsi method, but at the time of obtaining the corresponding iteractions in the results I get inf and nan values, could someone please guide me or tell me what its wrong?

```
from numpy import exp as e
 
Ri = 9
Rr = 10
i = 0
Er = 0
x = 1
 
def F(n):
    return 745*(1-e(-x/10))-49*x
 
#Funcion para calcular el error relativo
def error (Rra,Rrn):
    Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
    return Erel
 
 
print ('{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^25}'.format('# iter','Ri','Rs','Rr','F(Rr)','Erel(%)'))
 
while (i < 10):
    Er = error(Rra,Rr)
    Rra = Rr #Rra sera el Rr anterior para determinar el error relativo
    if F(Ri) * F(Rr) < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri) * F(Rr) > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es',Rr)
 
    Rr = (F(Rs)*Ri -F(Ri)*Rs)/(F(Rs) - F(Ri))
 
    i = i + 1
 
     #Condicional para el primer error relativo
 
    if i == 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr)))
    elif i > 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}{:^15.10f}{:^25.10f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr),Er))
```

Results

```
# iter           Ri             Rs             Rr            F(Rr)              Erel(%)
       0        10.0000000000  10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632
       1             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       2             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       3             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       4             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       5             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       6             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       7             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       8             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
       9             nan       10.0000000000       nan       21.8961235632            nan
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:30: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Comment: Where you have written `Rr = (F(Rs)*Ri -F(Ri)*Rs)/(F(Rs) - F(Ri))`, what do you expect to be the values of `Rs` and `Ri` the first time this runs? Therefore, what should be the result of `F(Rs) - F(Ri)`? Do you see how this causes a problem? Also: where is the initial value of `Rs` supposed to come from?

Comment: I add where come from the Rs values

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = 1
 
def F(n):
    return 745*(1-e(-x/10))-49*x
```

In your `F(n)` method, `x` is a value which is assigned to 1 and never changes. So `F(n)` will always return the same value `21.896123563210153`.

```py
    if F(Ri) * F(Rr) < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri) * F(Rr) > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es',Rr)
```

Therefore, `F(Ri) * F(Rr)` is always a positive value. Thus `Ri` has the same value of `Rr`.

```py
Rr = (F(Rs)*Ri -F(Ri)*Rs)/(F(Rs) - F(Ri))
```

You calculate `Rr` by dividing `F(Rs) - F(Ri)` which is 0. This is illegal in math. So `Rr` is `nan` in your case.

After the first loop, `Ri` is assigned the value of `Rr`.

```py
def error (Rra,Rrn):
    Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
    return Erel

Er = error(Rra,Rr)
```

The value of `Rrn` is `Rr`. In `(Rrn - Rra) / Rrn`, you divide a `nan` value. This results `nan`.

In summary, the root cause is that `x` in method `F(n)` is a constant value.